# Access django server in vagrant virtualbox on host machine?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding, vagrant-windows, zulip

I am using windows and putty to ssh to vagrant virtualbox.I cannot access the django server running in vagrant virtualbox using http://localhost:9991
I have disabled my firewall as well
here's my vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

def command?(name)
  `which #{name}`
  $?.success?
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # For LXC. VirtualBox hosts use a different box, described below.
  config.vm.box = "fgrehm/trusty64-lxc"

  # The Zulip development environment runs on 9991 on the guest.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9991, host: 9991, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/srv/zulip"

  # Specify LXC provider before VirtualBox provider so it's preferred.
  config.vm.provider "lxc" do |lxc|
    if command? "lxc-ls"
      LXC_VERSION = `lxc-ls --version`.strip unless defined? LXC_VERSION
      if LXC_VERSION >= "1.1.0"
        # Allow start without AppArmor, otherwise Box will not Start on Ubuntu 14.10
        # see https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-lxc/issues/333
        lxc.customize 'aa_allow_incomplete', 1
      end
    end
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, override|
    override.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    # 2GiB seemed reasonable here. The VM OOMs with only 1024MiB.
    vb.memory = 2048
  end

$provision_script = <<SCRIPT
set -x
set -e
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-pbs
/usr/bin/python /srv/zulip/provision.py
SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell",
    # We want provision.py to be run with the permissions of the vagrant user.
    privileged: false,
    inline: $provision_script
end
```

How do i access the server from host(Windows)?

Comment: did you try http://127.0.0.1:9991  ?

Comment: yes,it's not working as well

Comment: since you can ssh to the vagrant instance, i'm going to assume there's a problem with the provision.py that isn't actually opening port 9991.  Can you access localhost:9991 from *inside* the vagrant machine with something like telnet or netcat?

Comment: do you have a stripped down /srv/zulip/provision.py file?  I can't start up a vagrant and test without that.

Comment: i guess port 9991 is blocked, nc -z <host> <port>; echo $? gave me 1 as output which indicates port failure

Comment: @chugadie you can get provision.py from [this](https://github.com/zulip/zulip) repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106504/discussion-between-codefanatic23-and-chugadie).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest (on the Guest):

```
sudo netstat -lnutp
```

and having a look at what ports are open, and the process which owns them. If the one you want is missing, make sure the service which is responsible for it has been started, or start it yourself. From the looks of your Vagrantfile, this would be the "Zulip development environment".